# Ruby finding object instances already initialized

Tags: ruby

I have following Ruby program.

```
class A    
end

class B
  def method_b
    #find initialized instances of A
  end
end

a = A.new
b = B.new
b.method_b
```

can I find the already initialized instances of A while in method_b. Of course I agree that this can be easily done if I could pass the variable `a` to class B as `B.new(a)`. But I want to apply this in a more complex context where I need to avoid passing `a` so many times.

Comment: What is the significance of `b` in searching for the instances of `A`? What relation does `b` have to `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `ObjectSpace` module

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(A).count #count of the number of objects initialized for A
ObjectSpace.each_object(A).to_a #returns you the objects that are already initialized for A
```

You can find the documentation  for `ObjectSpace` module [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/ObjectSpace.html)

```
class B
  def method_b
    ObjectSpace.each_object(A).to_a
  end
end
```